# How to use AutoIt to click a button not recognized by its Finder Tool

Tags: autoit, mouseclick-event

I just found out about AutoIt being an alternative for automating mouse clicks.

I want to create a script that clicks on the "Yes, stop and exit" button of an application. The application is a screen recorder called Screencast-O-Matic (version 2.2.1).

Here's a screenshot of the application:

[image: Application Screenshot]

Here's the script I wrote:

```
Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]", "", 0)
ControlClick($hWnd, "Yes, stop and exit", "")
```

I don't know the control ID. I used the Finder tool to find it, but the finder tool just identified the class and not the control ID.

Here's a screenshot of AutoIt. It shows everything as blank.

[image: AutoIt when I hover over button]

How can I still click the button? Solutions involving something other than AutoIt  would also help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you find it with the [AutoIt Window Info](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm)? If not, I sometimes (as a last option) try to identify the window by the text in it and then use [MouseClick()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm) with screen coordinates for clicking on a button.

Comment: When I use the finder tool, it shows me window information - title, class, position, size etc but it doesn't show anything for controls. Everything is blank for controls. I'll add a screenshot for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem here is that the controls aren't WinAPI controls but self made controls created with images. You have to use the mouse position to click on that button (**MouseClick**). Maybe you have luck with `ControlClick("Screen-Cast-O-Matic", "", 0, "left",1, Xpos, Ypos)`

If the position of the button changes you could find out that position by using **PixelChecksum**.